# How to store Word documents in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I need to store `.docx` or `.doc` Word documents into a SQL Server 2008 database.
And I also need to retrieve these documents.

Please help to do this.. thank you.

Comment: A largeobject may be blob ,clob in the table might help you to store such details. But why you want to store such a huge data in database.

Comment: @vinayak your are right. but am already know this, we can't store data's as files in DB. i just clarify my doubt.. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finaly i got answer any file you can store into db:-

> Step 1: Get a document informations as a binary (Convert all **text into ascii binary** format becouse if you have any functional operator it will broke your **INSERT QUERY**).
>
> Step 2: Get Docment extensions for example (.docx, .pdf, .ppt) and include with your INSERT QUERY.

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string contentType = file.ContentType;

                byte[] fileData = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
                file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);

                string OriginalName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string Username = User.Identity.Name;

                Models.File myFile = new Models.File(contentType, OriginalName, fileData, Username);
                myFile.Save();
            }
```

> step 3: On Retriving your documents you can use like this

```
   public ActionResult Download()
    {
        string Originalname = string.Empty;
        byte[] FileData = null;
        var requestedID = RouteData.Values["id"];
        if (requestedID.ToString() != null)
        {
            Guid id = new Guid(requestedID.ToString());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Models.UsersGroups dt = new Models.UsersGroups();
            ds = dt.GetItem(id);
            foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Originalname = item["OriginalName"].ToString();
                FileData = (byte[])item["FileData"];
            }
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Originalname + "\"");
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileData);
        }
        return File(FileData, "application/x-unknown");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you could unpack the file into a string and then store that string in your database. You will probably need to use a blob column to hold the data. Then you could retrieve the string, repack it and store it in a file as a docx document before serving it to the user.

Comment: but it's not excepted my question

Answer (score -1):

First, this generally is not a good idea.  Generally, it is better to store a link to the file.

You could store the files in a varbinary(max) field as binary content.  You could also store it in a [filestream](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695918.aspx&ei=ok3fUvD7GYLmoASDwoKYDQ&usg=AFQjCNH9bdKtloOplChyPUg1oorHIuwUkA&sig2=Wbnpv1JYMXTZG2sZ21O-ng&bvm=bv.59568121,d.cGU), which is probably the better way to go.  Filestream keeps them somewhat separate, but permits them to be tracked and maintained along with the database.